# Moving items in arrays using enumeration

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsarray, enumeration

I've created a custom button in an accessory view in a `UITableViewCell`. The button acts a a customized check box in a list view.

I'd like to programmatically move "checked" items into a second section of the `UITableView`, but I'm running into difficulty doing this.

I'm following MVC and I'm using a BOOL, `didArrive`, in the following method to sort checked items:

```
- (void)shuffleGuests
{
    RCGuestManager *movedGuest = [[RCGuestManager alloc] init];
    for (id guest in allGuestsPending) {
        if ([guest didArrive]) {
            [allGuestsArrived addObject:guest];
            movedGuest = guest;
        }
    }
    [allGuestsPending removeObjectIdenticalTo:movedGuest];
}
```

Note the two arrays. Unchecked items should go into the allGuestsPending array and checked guests should go into the allGuestsArrived array.

This method is called when a row is tapped. The item is checked and then its moved from one section in the table view two another (matching the arrays).

I can't, of course, remove an object during enumeration so I'm attempting to put the moved object into a variable and then remove it from it's former array whilst adding it to the new array.

The above method results in the last item in the array always getting moved to the new section.

Is there a better way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: You just want to move all of the arrived guests to a different array?  This function will erase the last object in the pending array every time, regardless of whether or not the guests has arrived.  It will also leave the arrived guests in the pending array.  I think you made a mistake somewhere in your question...

Comment: Are all the guests instances of RCGuestManager? If so, why are you initializing `movedGuest` with a brand new guest that isn't in the array? If not, why are you initializing `movedGuest` with an RCGuestManager?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following idea instead:

```
NSMutableArray *guestsToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id guest in allGuestsPending) {
    if ([guest didArrive]) {
        [allGuestsArrived addObject: guest];
        [guestsToRemove addObject: guest];
    }
}
[allGuestsPending removeObjectsInArray: guestsToRemove];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your code. I tried this same approach yesterday too. Unfortunately the last name in the allGuestsArrived array is always placed into the 2nd section *and* that name is not removed from allGuestsPending array. When I step through the code everything seems to be working fine. The objects come and go. But in the table view, the objects are wrong. Perhaps there is another problem in my code. I think I'll write a smaller version to test this functionality. Thanks again.